# Css circles position

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, geometry

I have an effect on circle (paralax) on mouse move my circles are moving.(like here:
    [Tutorial paralax](http://jquery-jkit.com/commands/parallax.html))
    But how can I made this circle responsive and how can i change their position to have someting like this:
    [image]
 **Here are each circle:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
I want every circle to be as diffrent element. not one picture.



    <body>
    <div class="parallax-container" data-jkit="[parallax:strength=2;axis=both]">
            <div class="parallax paralax2"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/circle1.png"></div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3t5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>***[Hopefully this is what you are looking for..](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3t5/6/)***</kbd>

*HTML*

```
<div class="parallax-container" data-jkit="[parallax:strength=3;axis=both]">
    <div class="parallax small circle"></div>
    <div class="parallax medium circle"></div>
    <div class="parallax large circle"></div>
</div>
```

<kbd>***[See the result here... And even resize the browser to see it's responsiveness](http://jsfiddle.net/yq3t5/6/embedded/result/)***</kbd>

Comment: Thats good alternative 4 it. But my question is also how to place this tree circle like here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64675374/circle/circle1.png  using only css?

Comment: you need to specifically state `top` and `left` for each circle... To put it into a particular position

Comment: Ok but why it always on move jump to the center of screen?